# linking console to application so that the cmd box is not required

Tags: c#, winforms, console

I had a thought of adding the console like in Netbeans IDE in my application, where we need not go for the black cmd box, everything is shown within the IDE.. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need this:

```
Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
p.UseShellExecute = false;
p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.Write(result);
}
```

But your question is to broad. This can help to:

```
System("Put_Your_Console_Command_Here");
```

And the command will get executed as if you wrote that in the cmd.\

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the "Output" window?  Try Debug > Windows > Output from the toolbar in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yea but that is for the IDE right? what if I want to add that kind of feature in a winform application, so that when i click on execute button on my app it shows the output there instead of opening a black box to show the result..

Comment: Why not just create a label or a read-only multi-line text box on your form and populate it after the execute button is clicked?

Comment: But, It'll just show the things getting printed. What if I have to take a user input? like taking a choice etc!